How to schedule a periodic task with PainlessMesh for Arduino?
I am using Arduino PainlessMesh library to setup a WiFi mesh.
Documentation mentions that delay() is not compatible with this library. So all examples
and blogs use a Task Scheduler for running periodic client tasks.
My use case involves reading of a sensor every 10 seconds and broadcasting it to the mesh.
I feel the extra coding effort, size and complexity of the Scheduler is unnecessary for this simple periodic task.
I have always been using the following popular technique for running a task periodically:
void loop() {
  if(millis()-previousTimeStamp > 10000) {
     readSensor();
     // <now broadcast it to the mesh>
     previousTimeStamp = millis();
  }
}

I have tried this code, and it works fine along with the mesh. But I want to be sure about its correctness and long term stability.
Is this approach technically compatible with a WiFi mesh? Are there any hidden gotchas like interfering with timers or blocking interrupts etc? I need inputs from someone familiar with the inner working of the mesh protocol, or who has used this for a fairly long time without issues.
Bonus question:
My sensor is actually an SR-04 ultrasonic distance sensor. It calls delayMicroseconds() and pulseIn() functions to measure the timing of the ultrasonic pulse. Because of this, I am doubly worried about timers and interrupts. Again, the sensor works fine in practice, but what about theoretical correctness?
